# Why QWidget is changing geometry i set

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following code:

```
QWidget w(nullptr, Qt::Tool | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint);
w.setGeometry(9, 60, 475, 223);
w.show();
auto rect = w.geometry();
```

Variable `rect` has the same value I set `(9, 60, 475, 223)` but before the window is displayed on my desktop I get a `moveEvent(QMoveEvent *event)` where `y` coordinate obtained with same function `geometry()` become `88`.

As you can see this window has no parent (actually I suppose that in this case my desktop is it's parent anyway I think it's irrelevant) and I am using `geometry()` function and not `frameGeometry()`. For `frameGeometry` I am expecting coordinates to be different because of window title bar.

My questions are: Why does this happen? From where does this 28 (88-60) value comes? Can I consider it constant?

**What I tried:** `w.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Policy::MinimumExpanding,QSizePolicy::Policy::Mini‌​mumExpanding);` but nothing changed
`w.move(QPoint) w.resize(QSize);` with no result
I set a button and on it's click I reset geometry `w.setGeometry(9, 60, 475, 223);` and window is repositioning this time at the desired coordinates(no more +28 displacement)

**Edit:**
**Question2:** From where does this 28 (88-60) value comes?
**Answer:** I found that this 28 pixels actually are the height for unity topbar.

 **Question3:** Can I consider it constant?
 **Answer:** No. This size can be modified by user. This is actually the way I found where is this value from.

**Remaining Questions:** Why does this happen? And why does this happen just for first `setGeometry()` call and not for every call(read last thing I tried)?

Comment: as you set the windowtitle and minimizebutton hints I would say that the 28 pixels are the window title bar. You can read in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) that geometry() returns the frame without the title bar (88-28), 28 should be the fixed size of the title bar and frameGeometry() should return 88 (60 + 28). Do I misunderstand your question!?
Ps: you are right, top level widgets are relative to the desktop

Comment: The thing is i set the geometry() and get it back it's the same. But an moment later an moveEvent() is triggered and when i check geometry it's modified by something. PS. I am not messing with title bar and for me it's 24 i got it with style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_TitleBarHeight);

Comment: The `w.geometry()` is called just after you set that geometry 2 lines above. At that moment the geometry is still as you desire, because no other events were processed by the Qt.

Then Qt processes events from the queue and does numerous things, including call to your mouse event (you mentioned you check the geometry from there again) and the event where Qt updates size of your widget according to its settings. Those settings are most likely set so the widget resizes to "fit its contents". That's why Qt resizes it to different geometry. Try with `w.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding)`

Comment: I tried `w.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Policy::MinimumExpanding,QSizePolicy::Policy::MinimumExpanding);` but nothing changed :(